# Vodafone Mobile Broadband K3765-Z not working in jessie but was working in wheezy

Tags: networking, usb, debian, wireless, umts

I was working on Debian stable=wheezy until last week. Using my Surfstick was fine - configured by network-Manager.
After updating to jessie I'm not able to connect.

The stick is properly found.
`lsusb` shows
`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 19d2:2002 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM`

`nmcli` results in

```
=============================================================================
                          Status von NetworkManager
=============================================================================
STATUS           KONNEKTIVITÄT  WLAN-HW    WLAN       WWAN-HW    WWAN      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
nicht verbunden  kein           aktiviert  aktiviert  aktiviert  aktiviert



==================================================
                Status der Geräte
==================================================
GERÄT     TYP       STATUS           VERBINDUNG 
--------------------------------------------------
cdc-wdm0  gsm       nicht verbunden  --         
eth0      ethernet  nicht verfügbar  --         
lo        loopback  nicht verwaltet  --         


============================================
                Funkschalter
============================================
WLAN-HW    WLAN       WWAN-HW    WWAN      
--------------------------------------------
aktiviert  aktiviert  aktiviert  aktiviert


===========================================================================================
                             NetworkManager Verbindungsprofile
===========================================================================================
NAME                         UUID                                  TYP             GERÄT 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vodafone Vorgabe             658660a8-5801-4d6c-968b-de67634bd566  gsm             --    
Kabelgebundene Verbindung 1  d7f13745-d46d-4bb8-9a58-1629b5436441  802-3-ethernet  --
```

The connection could not be established.
Neither via `nmcli` nor by `gnome-app` nor by `wvdial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I found a solution (at least for me):
It seems, there is a problem with PIN-locked SIM-Cards.
After setting up the GSM-Connection via the GUI nothing happended (seemed so). But a file for the connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` has been created.
By disabling the PIN of the SIM-Card or by inserting a `pin=####` (of course replace by you PIN) line into the connection profile worked fine.
For further help, I`ll show my file over here:

```
[connection]
id=Vodafone Vorgabe
uuid=b998ecec-9aec-4f3a-a129-efc5e5a7d60d
type=gsm
autoconnect=true

[gsm]
number=*99#
apn=web.vodafone.de
pin=####

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ppp]
lcp-echo-failure=5
lcp-echo-interval=30

[serial]
baud=115200

[ipv4]
method=auto
```